# How can I access instance of a model to get the fileds data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I created an Address model:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    address1 = models.CharField("Address lines 1", max_length=128)
    ...
```

in my views.py when I try to access the data, it doesn give me anything, this is what I've tried:

`user_AddressForm = AddressForm(instance=request.user.profile)`

and

`user_AddressForm = AddressForm(address_listNames)` 
where address_listNames is are the objects: 
`<QuerySet [<Address: Elizabeth's house>, <Address: Work>, <Address: Home>]>`

When I display the form in the html:

```
{% for address in user_AddressForm %}
    {{ address }}
{% endfor %}
```

it's empty, I'm only getting 2 zipcodes, how can I get the data?

Thank you

Comment: If you want only to show the data (`Address` instance data), why do you want to use forms?

Answer (score 0):

so the answer was fairly simple, but I couldn't see it because of another error. To access this model instance I just did:

`user_AddressForm = AddressForm(instance=address_listNames)`

where address_listNames contains the list of addresses of the current user.